# Check for sums in array Java

Tags: java, arrays

I'm doing a dice game called Thirty in Java. I have an array with the values of the dice like [1, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6]. From that array I want to be able to find every group that gives a given sum, but every dice can only be counted once.

For example if I have the array [1, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6] and want to find every group that equals 12, that will give me for example 1+5+6=12 and 3+4+5=12.

And with an example like [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 6] I will get 1+1+1+1+2+6=12.

There will always be 6 dice but the sum I'm looking for can be anything between 4 and 12.

Can someone please help me? I don't really have any code to give and it would only be confusing and would't help at all.

Comment: I think this problem can be solved using greedy algorithm, take a look at http://www.tutorialspoint.com/data_structures_algorithms/greedy_algorithms.htm

Comment: you should consider looking at a graph in which each number is a node in the graph and its neighbors are every other node. Then, use brute force by doing a modified breadth first search on each node to check every single combination to see if it equals the sum.

Comment: Related: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/36214/find-all-subsets-of-an-int-array-whose-sums-equal-a-given-target

Answer (score 0):

I have an algorithm that resolves your problem, but you will have to adapt it to your need.
Unfortunately I don't know if it is part of any specific known data structure.

In short, I would say that it transforms your array in binary positions and loop on it from where none of the items are flagged to where all of them are flagged.

- Array size = 6
- Initial flagged array = "000000"  // 6 positions unflagged
- Final flagged array   = "111111"  // 6 positions flagged

Incrementing the binary array, it sums just the positions flagged. We will be able to sum all possible combinations.

**TEST 1**

Given your parameters:

- Sum = 12
- Array = {1, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6}

The result is:

```
Position: 011010  // means the sum of item in position 1,2,4 (3 + 4 + 5 = 12)
Position: 011100  // means the sum of item in position 1,2,3 (3 + 4 + 5 = 12)
Position: 100011  // means the sum of item in position 0,4,5 (1 + 5 + 6 = 12)
Position: 100101  // means the sum of item in position 0,3,5 (1 + 5 + 6 = 12)
```

**TEST 2**

Given your parameters:

- Sum = 12
- Array = {1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 6}

The result is:

```
Position: 111111  // means the sum of item in position 0,1,2,3,4,5 (1+1+1+1+2+6 = 12)
```

The code may be improved, but is as follows, printing simply "1" to the positions to be summed, that result to the desired number.

```js
public class Algorithm {

public static void main(String[] args) {
 Algorithm checkSum = new Algorithm();

 Integer[] array = {1, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6};
 Integer sum = 12;
 checkSum.find(array, sum);
 
 System.out.println("------------------");
 
 Integer[] array2 = {1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 6};
 Integer sum2 = 12;
 checkSum.find(array2, sum2);
}

private void find(Integer[] array, Integer sum) {
 // This could be replaced by a StringUtils lib to fill with "1" the size of the array
 String maxBinary = "";
 for (int i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
  maxBinary += "1";
 }
 
 int maxDecimal = Integer.parseInt(maxBinary, 2);
 
 // This will iterate from "000000" to "111111"
 for (int i=0; i<=maxDecimal; i++) {
  String binaryNumber = lpad(Integer.toBinaryString(i), array.length);
  
  int checkSum = 0;
  for (int j=0; j<binaryNumber.length(); j++) {
   if ("1".equals(binaryNumber.substring(j,j+1))) {
    checkSum += array[j]; 
   }
  }
  // This is the check to see if the sum is the desired one
  if (sum == checkSum) {
   System.out.println("Positions: " + binaryNumber);
  } 
 }
}

/**
 * This is a simple LPAD function to add zeros to the left of the string. 
 */
private String lpad(String text, Integer size) {
 String regex = "%0"+ size + "d";
 return String.format(regex, Integer.parseInt(text));
}
}
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Here a not extremely well tested and perhaps a bit naiv solution. I use Lists of Integers, because I don't like arrays, sorry!

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

public class PickNumbersTest {

    private List<Integer> numbers;

    @Before
    public void before() {
        Integer[] ints = new Integer[] { 1, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6 };
        numbers = new ArrayList<>();
        numbers.addAll(Arrays.asList(ints));        
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {

        PickNumbers p = new PickNumbers();
        List<List<Integer>> result = p.pick(12,  numbers);

        System.out.println(result);
    }
}

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class PickNumbers {

    public List<List<Integer>> pick(final int sum, final List<Integer> values) {

        // make a copy to avoid making changes to passed in List
        List<Integer> numbers = copy(values);

        List<List<Integer>> results = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();

        while (!pickSingle(sum, numbers).isEmpty()) {

            List<Integer> currentResult = pickSingle(sum, numbers);

            results.add(currentResult);
            currentResult.forEach(i -> numbers.remove(i));

        }

        return results;
    }

    protected List<Integer> pickSingle(final int sum, final List<Integer> values) {
        int rest = sum;
        List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
        Picker p = new Picker(values);

        while (rest > 0 && p.hasNext()) {

            int i = p.next();

            if (i > rest) {
                p.remove();
            } else if (i == rest) {
                result.add(i);
                return result;
            } else { // i < rest
                result.add(i);
                p.remove();
                rest = rest - i;
            }
        }

        return new ArrayList<>();
    }

    private List<Integer> copy(final List<Integer> values) {

        List<Integer> copy = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        copy.addAll(values);

        return copy;
    }
}

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class Picker {

    private List<Integer> values = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    public Picker(final List<Integer> values) {

        this.values.addAll(values);
        this.values.sort(null);
        Collections.reverse(this.values);
    }

    public int next() {

        return values.get(0);
    }

    public void remove() {

        values.remove(0);
    }

    public boolean hasNext() {

        return values.size() > 0;
    }
}
```